Extracting Medical Condition as English Label from Wikidata
I'm trying to extract people named George who possibly have a medical condition. This is my query:
SELECT ?name ?name_label ?condition ?condition_name ?occupationLabel ?fullName
WHERE
{
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en" }
?name p:P1050 ?condition.
?name wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
?name p:P735 ?givenName.
?givenName (ps:P735/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q15921732.

OPTIONAL {?name rdfs:label ?name_label FILTER (lang(?name_label) = "en") .}
OPTIONAL {?condition rdfs:label ?condition_name FILTER (lang(?condition_name) = "en").}
OPTIONAL {?name wdt:P106 ?occupation.}
OPTIONAL {?name wdt:P1559 ?fullName.}
}
ORDER BY ASC (?name)

This sort of works except that it returns a Wikidata statement (wds) for the condition but nothing for condition_name. How can I get an English label for it?

p: prefixes do always refer to the statements. So either also link to ps: in a second triple pattern (?name p:P1050/ps:P1050 ?condition. ) or simply use wdt: as prefix instead ( ?name wdt:P1050 ?condition.  ) .
